# NTBackup problems on shutdown

Tags: backup, shutdown, filesize

I'm trying to lunch ntbackup on shutdown but the backup file (.bkf) is only 1.1 GB instead of 2.2 GB. When i try to restore using this file ntbackup tells me that it is corrupted. If i run the same command as bat file it works (the command is: `ntbackup backup C:\ systemstate /m normal /f "X:\Backup_20-12-2010.bkf" /j "Bckp_Data-and-System" /L:s` ). The log file tells me that everything is ok. What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set in gpedit.msc at `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Scripts` the key `Maximum wait time for Group Policy scripts` to 0. The default time is 600 seconds (10 minutes).